# How to initialize this generic class

Tags: typescript

In this class definition its contructor parameter depends itself. So how should correctly initialize this class?

```
export class TreeNode<T> {
  constructor(public value: T, public children: TreeNode<T>[]) {}

  toString(): string { return `TreeNode(${this.value})`; }
}
```

(source :https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/utils/tree.ts)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can give it an empty list, like:

```
new TreeNode<Number>(0, [])
```

Or, if you want it to have children, do like this:

```js
new TreeNode<Number>(0, [
    new Number(1, []),
    new TreeNode<Number>(1, [])
])
```

Comment: new Number Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript can infer the type based on what's passed to the constructor, whatever value you give it will be the generic being inferred.

```
const node = new TreeNode(42, []); // TreeNode's T will be inferred to 'number'.
```

You can also explicitly pass a type argument, although inferring is *usually* preferable.

```
const node = new TreeNode<string>('Hello World', []);
```

[Example on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOBTRA5A9gE0QHlgPmgG8BYAKGmmDQDsIAXeAV2DrXgAoAHRgIxAEtg0AG5gQjRAC44AGmjc+gygAt+IDEmrSEydFlx4A2gF0AlEQC+ZMhVYBlBv2oBzdqen14T50WhI6jPDU0AAGOqiYiOwAJIR0qhAAdKLiiBamIQDc0FakuWRUtHTQ1IwAtjyI8HqI0AC8JYgA7nBIEVjsACwATHImppnWpIX00J7eNfWNLeE12OMueOwA5AASiCAgaMt9ZoOkBTSjVfBskw3Uza26kdilFVVLaxtbO9D9mUA)